# Not reading connected Android phone

Tags: usb, android

I have just upgraded ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. Whenever I try to connect my android, it just charges and nothing else. I have tried changing cables and trying with multiple android devices but still doesn't work.

Then I tried changing usb port, it worked on 3.0 but when I tried to access my files, it showed:

[image]

Comment: Did you select "file transfer" (or something similar) in your Android device? Otherwise, by default it only charges.

Comment: I tried selecting other options as well, including "file transfer" and "transfer photos"

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Just typed this on terminal:

```
adb devices
```

It showed that daemon has started successfully and is able to read connected android devices.

Comment: This didn't work for me.